# how to return only fields that have a value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a query builder form that allows a user to enter values into fields that once complete allows them to pass the entered values to a search field. Not all the fields have to be completed by the user within the form.

sample of html

```
<div id="advanceSearchCriteria">
    <div class="searchHeader">Person</div>
    <div class="contentBorders" id="person">
        <div class="searchdiv">
            <span class="smLabel">Last Name</span><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" size="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="searchdiv">
            <span class="smLabel">First Name</span><br />
            <input type="text" name="namefirst" value="" size="15" />
        </div>
        <div class="searchdiv">
            <span class="smLabel">Middle Name</span><br />
            <input type="text" name="namemiddle" value="" size="10" />
        </div>
        <div class="searchdiv">
            <span class="smLabel">Suffix</span><br />
            <input type="text" name="suffix1" value="" size="5" />
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Within jQuery I created a function to pass the values of the fields to an asp.net textbox control

```
    function setAdvancedSearchString() {
    checkField();
    var txt = $("input[name='tbsearchterm']");
    var fields = $("#advanceSearchCriteria :input").serializeArray();
    jQuery.each(fields, function (i, field) {
        if (txt) {
            txt.val(txt.val() + field.name + ": " field.value + " ");
        }
    });
}
```

With the current approach this returns all input fields and their values. What I would like to have is only fields that contain a value entered by the user to be serialized and passed to search term. For example if the user only entered last name I would only like that fieldname and value returned (lastname: james)

I've tried to test for null on the var fields but my syntax is wrong or I am testing for null in the wrong location

So far I have tried the following:

```
var fields = if($("#advanceSearchCriteria :input") != null) 
{
$("#advanceSearchCriteria :input").serializeArray();
}
```

but this seems to cause a compile error.

Can anyone provide some help on how to only serialize and return fieldnames and values that have a value entered?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`attribute not equals selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) to select fields with text and you don't have to use `.serializeArray()`. Check this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/C2Q9D/1/)):

```
function setAdvancedSearchString() {
   checkField();
   var txt = $("input[name='tbsearchterm']");
    $("#advanceSearchCriteria :input[value!='']").each(function(i, field) {
        txt.val(function(index, value) {
            return [value, field.name, ": ", field.value, " "].join('');
        });
    });
}
```

**Extra**
I used an anonymous function for setting the value of `txt` and used array/join for string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips. As a side question is it safe to assume that if I do not need to create a json object array/join is the simpler approach. This seems more readable to me over jquery serializeArray.

Comment: It's up to you. If you don't work with large datasets then readability may be your priority.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function setAdvancedSearchString() {
    checkField();
    var txt = $("input[name='tbsearchterm']");
    var fields = $("#advanceSearchCriteria :input").serializeArray();
    jQuery.each(fields, function (i, field) {
        if (txt && field.value !='') {
            txt.val(txt.val() + field.name + ": " field.value + " ");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TnrWQ/)** here

you can use `:input [value != '']`. Check my version below,

```
function setAdvancedSearchString() {
   checkField();
   var txt = $("input[name='tbsearchterm']");
   var fields = $("#advanceSearchCriteria :input[value != '']").serializeArray();
   jQuery.each(fields, function (i, field) {
     if (txt) {
        txt.val(txt.val() + field.name + ": " field.value + " ");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip and demo this was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#advanceSearchCriteria :input").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).val() != ""; 
}).serializeArray();
```